# Queueing framework solution

Tags: c#, .net, queue, task-queue

I would like to address such a issue: I have a HTML form (like register form) which submission sends email. Now I send it as a part of page request. Obvious drawbacks:

- makes request longer
- sometimes smtp server is down, or timeouts and emails are not sent

When working with PHP I used a solution that based on queue - I had been putting an object/xml to queue host, and then some kind of client checked that queue. If queue task was sucessfully handled it removed task from queue. I wonder, is there a similar implementation on Windows / .NET platform ?

Thanks,Paweł

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is robust queuing offered by [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is easy to use in .NET. [Accessing Message Queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978425.aspx) might be a good place to start.

Comment: Looks fine. I completely forgot about MSMQ... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AH - why?

> I have a HTML form (like register form) which submission sends email.

Have the submission write the email to a local drop directory, then use the SMTP service of the Windows system to submit them to your providers email server. Alternatively use your own service to copy them to the outgoing email pickup folder (I do that so I can put in a code pointing to the website for tracking).

These are provided standard methods.

Comment: Wow. Write email content to hard drive? What about email subject, to, from, cc etc properties that I set when sending email? Sorry, but could you elaborate a bit? :)

Comment: Simple. EMAIL is a text file that is transported by HTTP. It is fully encoded and - carefull - includes FULL HEADER INFORMATION, including sender and recipients. No problem extracting those again. http://imar.spaanjaars.com/496/using-a-local-pickup-folder-for-email-delivery

Comment: I must have switched off thinking :) I though you ment plain HTML email content.... Anyway, it looks interesting. What about sending those emails? I just bumped into some articles that claim that it's not straightforward to load eml file and send it? How do you send them?

Comment: As I said - you can just write them into the local SMTP service pickup folder. Guess why this is called pickup folder. Hint: The server automatically picks up the emails ;) And sends them.

Comment: Ah, I got confused, as it's said in above article that "...From now on, your e-mail is dropped in the local folder C:\TempMail as .eml files. ..."

Answer (score 0):

You don't neccessarily need a queue as such.  You can use the SendAsync method on the System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient class.  That will return immediately and not block the page.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately application is using 3rd party lib email solution. But good to know that such a class exists in .NET , thanks though! Also want to put it in queue as it happened many times recently, what SMTP server was down.

Comment: I don't know why you'd need a 3rd party email solution.  They are usually snake oil.  The built in one is fine.  You can deliver mail to a local IIS SMTP server and relay that to your real one if you have SMTP delivery reliability problems.